# Создать пользовательский класс DateTime

Tags: c#

Моя задача - реализовать собственный класс `DateTime`, атрибутами которого являются секунды, минуты, часы, дни месяца, месяца, года. У меня возникли трудности с реализацией методов  `void AddDays(int N)`, `AddMonth(int N)`, `AddYears(int N)`. Функции должны работать правильно, учитывать прибавление в високосном и обычном году. Пытался повторить устройство системного класса, но не получилось понять идею. Подскажите какие-нибудь соображение по правильному устройству этих функций.

```
public TimeDate(int second, int minute, int hour,
            int day, int month, int year)
        {
            _second = second;
            _minute = minute;
            _hour = hour;
            _day = day;
            _month = month;
            _year = year;
        }
        private long _second;
        private long _minute;
        private long _hour;
        private long _day;
        private long _month;
        private long _year;
        private long[] dayYear = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        private long[] dayYearLeap ={0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

        private bool isLeap()
        {
            if (_year % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (_year % 100 == 0)
                {
                    if (_year % 400 == 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
public void AddDays(int N)
        {
            long N_in_second = N * 60*60*24;
            long second_now = _second + _minute * 60 + _hour * 60 * 60 + _day * 60 * 60 * 24;
            if (isLeap())
            {
                second_now +=  _month*3600*24*dayYearLeap[_month]+
                              _year * 60 * 60 * 24 * dayYearLeap[_month] * 12;
            }
            else
            {
                second_now += _month * 3600 * 24 * dayYear[_month] +
                              _year * 60 * 60 * 24 * dayYear[_month] * 12;
            }

            second_now += N_in_second;
            _year = second_now / (60*60*24*12*dayYear[_month]);
            second_now -= 60 * 60 * 24 * 12 * dayYear[_month];
            _month = second_now / (60 * 60 * 24 * dayYear[_month]) % 12;
            if (_month == 0) _month = 12;
            second_now -= (60 * 60 * 24 * dayYear[_month]);
            _day = second_now / (60 * 60 * 24) % dayYear[_month];
            second_now -= (60 * 60 * 24);
            _hour = second_now / (60 * 60) % 24;
            second_now -= (60 * 60);
            _minute = second_now / 60 % 60;
            second_now -= 60;
            _second = second_now % 60;
        }
```

При вводе  `TimeDate date = new TimeDate(34,27,13,28,2,2019);date.AddDays(1);` На выходе получаем: `Second: 34, Minute: 27, Hour: 13, Day: 8, Month: 3,Year: 2019`. Добавились лишние 7 дней. Как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: с методами `AddMonth` и `AddYears` не должно быть проблем

Comment: @aepot, а попробуй просто написать метод `AddDays` учитывающий високосность

Comment: По поводу `Функции должны работать правильно, учитывать прибавление в високосном и обычном году`. Смотрите: во-первых, вы не описали проблему, вы описали задачу. Ну окей. А попробуйте накидать код класса, потом написать тестовые сценарии которые не проходят. Пока вы проговариваете проблему слишком  общими словами, без конкретики -- у вас мышление и не включается. (Кстати, не включится оно и если вам просто дадут подсказку, как делать правильно).

Comment: @AK, проблема очевидна - непонятно как делать добавление дней, чтобы в результате получилась верная дата.

Comment: @Grundy Берем данные о количестве дней в каждом месяце, берем 1972 год как високосный (любой високосный подойдет), и поехали. Если `Math.Abs(текущий год - 1972) % 4 == 0`, то в феврале 29 дней, иначе 28.

Comment: @aepot, и как это использовать в методе `AddDays`? :-)

Comment: Возможно стоит отталкиваться от одной переменной, например секунд. Считать все время в секундах, а остальные данные получать свойствами. Тогда и с AddDays не возникнет проблем.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler, возникнут при переводе в конкретную дату.

Comment: @Grundy это экзамен? функция, крутит в цикле месяцы начиная с текущего вычитая из добавляемого значения количества дней, при условии что после вычитания значение не станет отрицательным, иначе месяц++. Если месяц == 13, то месяц = 1, год++. Как только случилось, что вычесть нельзя, выход из цикла, добавление остатка текущему дню, если сумма > количества дней в текущем месяце, то месяц++, день -= количество дней в текущем месяце. Считайте, что это код. :) Возможно, можно оптимизировать, код писал в уме.

Comment: @aepot, почему бы не сделать вместо комментария ответ?

Comment: Предлагаю поступить как настоящие программисты: в минуте 64 секунды, в часу - 64 минуты, в месяце 32 дня, в году - 256 дней и т. п. Айтишный календарь, так сказать. Реализуется просто. Високосность отменить. Неравномерное движение планеты Земля вокруг Солнца поправить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ахаха, а точка отсчета (нулевой год) - 1 января 1970, я полагаю? И какая сегодня дата? Движение земли фиксить не обязательно, потому что напротив монитора всегда лето, и временами года можно пренебречь.

Comment: @Grundy потому что _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу._

Comment: @aepot, если ты уже дал ответ в комментарии, почему не перенести его в ответы? Про данную причину закрытия много споров, и она на самом деле не нужна.

Comment: Какая-то вот [такая](https://pastebin.com/cTG8T9xS) идея, по аналогии можно и остальные свойства получить

Comment: По-моему, вам надо создать еще один класс `TimeSpan`, который бы выражал временной отрезок в секундах, в минутах и т.д. И начать писать его с вычисления секундных отрезков и далее увеличивая продолжительность. После того как будет реализован это класс, вы его сможете использовать в `AddDay()` и проч.методах.

Comment: @Bulson, не очень понимаю как это поможет избежать ошибку. Да код станет более читабельным, но мне хочется не тратить лишние силы и время на написание лабы, а направить их на интересные проекты. Поэтому я и написал сюда, чтобы не сидеть недели над одной лабой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void AddDays(int N)
        {
            if (N >= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    _day++;
                    if (isLeap())
                    {
                        if (_day > dayYearLeap[_month])
                        {
                            _day = 1;
                            _month++;
                            if (_month > 12)
                            {
                                _year++;
                                _month = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_day > dayYear[_month])
                        {
                            _day = 1;
                            _month++;
                            if (_month > 12)
                            {
                                _year++;
                                _month = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.Abs(N); i++)
                {
                    _day--;

                    if (_day == 0)
                    {
                        _month--;
                        if (isLeap())
                        {
                            if (_month < 1)
                            {
                                _year--;
                                _month = 12;
                            }

                            _day = dayYearLeap[_month];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (_month < 1)
                            {
                                _year--;
                                _month = 12;
                            }

                            _day = dayYear[_month];
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```